# REST API with OpenRasta and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, openrasta

REST API Questions:

1. Does anyone know any good tutorial that shows how to do form based authentication with OpenRasta?
2. How difficult would it be to convert REST API from MVC to OpenRasta in future?
3. I know OpenRasta has advantages over MVC. 
   How about performance? Like to see some benchmark.

I am exploring OpenaRasta for ASP.NET C# app

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2):

1) No tutorial as such, if you want ot use forms authentication and you run on asp.net, that works just as usual, nothing changes much. You can still verify permissioning using the Requires* attributes.

2) Depends on you architect it. OpenRasta is resource based, MVC pushes you to be method-based, so you'll end up with systems that look and smell quite different depending on which way you go.

3) Never ran any benchmarks. The NHS, Huddle etc are all running it on high traffic sites and don't seem to have found any issues.